# Can't Add new local library Folder in Steam: New Steamlibrary folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions

Tags: permissions, mount, steam, libraries

I have steam client installed on my SSD. And I have games installed on secondary HD. When I go to Settings and Add Library Folder I navigate to 
`/media/user/Storage/Programs/steamapps` and select. It gives the error

> New Steamlibrary folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions.

So I tried to unmount my drive and remount it. Same error. Then I right clicked the folder and checked that the permissions were set to Create and delete files. Same error. The file system is showing Owner:Me.

I am running Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: So I tried to mount via terminal instead of just through the ubuntu files app.  And this is what I got: 

'$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/storagehd
[sudo] password for user: 
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only' 

So seeing this I might need to reformat that HD which sucks because all of the steam games are on it.

Comment: I have a 3rd HD that Windows is on. So it shouldn't have any files on this HD at all. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.  I had to disable Windows Fast Start inside of Win10 because I didn't have the option in my bios (mobo: AsRock Extreme4 Z77).  Once I did that then I did a shut down in Windows and booted Ubuntu.  I ran the same command and added the library successfully.